# Is there a Java thread pool object which automatically load balances threads across the available cores or is this done for you by the JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, multicore, threadpoolexecutor

Is there a Java thread pool object which automatically load balances threads across the available cores or is this done for you by the JVM?

Comment: Based on experience I'd claim it is taken care of by JVM.

Comment: @JensKrogsboell,  How would you know whether it was the JVM or the underlying operating system?

Comment: Good point - it was on windows XP as far as I remember.

Comment: But is it not exactly that kind of abstraction from the physical platform that the JVM is supposed to provide - if not provided by OS?

Comment: jvm threads = os threads. So it's the OS (or lower) that balances running threads on CPU cores.

Answer (score 4):

Since (most) JVMs use native threads, the scheduling of the threads is the responsibility to the operating system. There may well still be "green thread" implementations of the JVM (or, at least options for them, especially on older JVMs), but since "green threads" are implemented by the JVM itself, they tend to not scale across cores. A primary goal of using native threads was multi-processor compatibility. The JVM doesn't, typically, run at a low enough level within the operating environment to have control over a resource like the CPUs of the machine.

I keep qualifying which JVM because while the vast majority of folks use the Oracle/OpenJDK JVM, there are other JVMs, older JVMs, JVMs on embedded hardware that do not behave as the Oracle/OpenJDK JVM does.